# Show that for two $n\times n$ matrices, $A, B$ similar implies that ($A-λI$) and ($B-λI$) are similar for any $λI$ in $R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Proof check: Show that for two $n\times n$ matrices, $A, B$ similar implies that ($A-λI$) and ($B-λI$) are similar for any $λI$ in $\Bbb R$?

Let $λ$ be arbitrary.

By assumption there exists a matrix $C$ s.t. $A=CBC^{-1}$

WTS: there exists a matrix $D$ s.t. $A-λI$=$D(B-λI)D^{-1}$

Take D=C

$I=DID^{-1}$ since any matrix is similar to itself, or more helpfully $λI=DλID^{-1}$

By assumption $A=CBC^{-1}=DBD^{-1}$

Putting this together we have $A-λI=DBD^{-1}-DλID^{-1}=D(B-λI)D^{-1}$ as needed

My hangup is that I never use the fact that I is the identity matrix. Wouldn't this work for any matrix then, since any matrix is similar to itself?

edit: Would it be correct to say that my error in thinking here was that while for any matrix $A$ it is true that there exists another matrix $B$ s.t. $A=BAB^{-1}$ it is only true for the identity matrix and its scalar multiples that for any invertible matrix $D$, $I=DID^{-1}$?

Comment: No, $I=DID^{-1}$ only works for $I$ the identity in general.

Comment: Identity matrix commutes with any other matrix, so that $DID^{-1} = IDD^{-1} = I$.

Comment: You only need it to show that similar matrices have the same eigenvalues, whence the $A-\lambda I$.

Comment: @Bernard $\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 0\\ 
  0 & 0
  \end{array}$ and $\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 1\\ 
  0 & 0
  \end{array}$ are similar?

Comment: Oh I see I think I understand now. While for any matrix $A$ it is true that there exists another matrix $B$ s.t. $A=BAB^{-1}$ it is only true for the identity matrix that for any matrix $D$, $I=DID^{-1}$?

Comment: Certainly not, since the second matrix has rank $1$.

Comment: It is also true for scalar multiples of $I$. And certainly not all matrices $D$ have an inverse.

Comment: @Bernard Then how do you show to matrices are similar by showing they share same eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the corrections and all the help @Bernard!

Comment: @QuangHoang You are confusing the direction. $A$ similar to $B$ implies that the eigenvalues are equal, not the other way around.

Comment: @QuangHoang: having the same eigenvalues does not guarantee they're similar. It's only the converse which holds.

Comment: @Bernard My point is that, your other comment is not relevant to OP's question. OP's asking for similarity. Or am I missing something?

Comment: As I interpreted the question, the O.P. wodered whether whether his (her) proof was correct because the fact that there was specifically  the identity matrix was never used. I just answerred it was not specific to this matrix, except that later, it used to obtain the eigenvalues. In other words I tried to explain (maybe not clearly enough) why the identity matrix is there.

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ and $B$ are similar, then $A = C^{-1}BC$ for some invertible matrix $C$. However, then **for the same matrix $C$**, so does the following: $C^{-1}(B-\lambda I)C = C^{-1}BC - C^{-1}\lambda I C$ $=A - C^{-1}\lambda I C = A-\lambda C^{-1}IC = A-\lambda I$.

So if $A$ and $B$ are similar, then $A-\lambda I$ and $B-\lambda I$ are similar for any scalar $\lambda$.

Comment: Oh very cool, thanks for this proof, did not think of going this direction.

Answer (score 0):

If, say, we don't have $\lambda $ times the identity matrix,  but even a diagonal matrix $D'$ with different entries on the diagonal,  we don't get $D'= DD'D^{-1}$ in general.